# PHP's file-path component functions return incorrect results

Tags: php, path, filenames, filepath

You can get parts of a full file path using array notation, like

```
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

But aside from "basename" being named incorrectly (since it returns the whole filename), the 'basename' and 'filename' versions only return the first character of the filename.  If the filename is **Archive.zip** and I do the following:

```
echo "Here's the zip filename: " . $zipFilename . "<br>";
echo "Here's the basename: " . $zipFilename['basename'] . "<br>";
echo "Here's the 'filename': " . $zipFilename['filename'];
```

I get:

```
Here's the zip filename: Archive.zip
Here's the basename: A
Here's the 'filename': A
```

If I try it on the full path, **uploads/Archive.zip**, I get:

```
Here's the zip filename: uploads/Archive.zip
Here's the basename: u
Here's the 'filename': u
```

Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: By the way this file you are referring is uploaded by POST/GET? What is the scenario here?

Comment: How you are setting value/file to $zipFilename?

Comment: Yes, it's for uploaded files. $zipFilename comes from the POST (the name of the user-selected file), however the same thing happens if I hard-code it. Thanks for your comment, though; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's a missing step here: Calling `pathinfo` to turn the path string into an array.  Pramod's comment pointed me to this problem, although it's not quite right: pathinfo doesn't create an array of FILEs.  It just parses a string into an array.

Thanks!